# Как получить список созданных объектов произвольного класса

Tags: php, ооп

есть:

```php
    class MyClass {}
    $a = new MyClass();
    $b = new MyClass();
    $d = new MyClass();
    // etc...
```

нужно получить что-то вроде:

```php
    Array
        (
          [0] => a
          [1] => b
          [3] => c
          // etc...
        )
```

**Собственно вопрос:** 
«Как получить для пользовательского класса `MyClass` список созданных по нему объектов?», Есть ли встроенная в php-функция?

Comment: Получить-то можно. Что Вы потом с этим списком собираетесь делать?

Comment: Производить манипуляции с теми объектам, которые принадлежат именно классу `MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

Встроенной функции нет, насколько я знаю, но можно получить через суперглобальную переменную $GLOBALS.

Т.е. можно пройтись по его элементам в цикле и проверять, является ли элемент объектом определенного класса.

Comment: этот вариант оставил на крайний случай, как более ресурсоёмкий. Он потребует перебора всех переменных и проверки на имя класса. Надеюсь, что кто-то подскажет встроенную php функцию на подобии `ReflectionClass::`